# Bootstrap drop-down not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using the bootstrap drop-down in rails and it suddenly stopped working. If I raise the click event on the link manually like `$('a.dropdown-toggle').click()` it works fine, but if I actually click on it nothing happens.

If I attach a click handler using jQuery like `$('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){alert('foo');})` then that fires when I click on the link.

Is this because the event is being swallowed by something? Is there any way to figure out what it is?

I can't reproduce the error in a jsFiddle-type environment, but here is the relevant html:

```
   <li class="profile">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
          Ben
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="User">
            <li><a href="/users/edit.5399e28681f150251b000001"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Admin</li>
            <li><a href="/#providers"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Providers</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/patients"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> Patients</a></li>
              <li><a href="/admin/users"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Users</a></li>
              <li><a href="/logs/index"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Logs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
```

UPDATE: I've found that if I call `$('a.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`a few seconds after the page loads it works, but not if I call it right when the page loads. Also my accordions have a similar problem – they can drop down but they don't close back up unless you manually call the click event. So I'm guessing that right now it's due to something swallowing the click event, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Add some code to reproduce the problem, even if it's not in a Fiddle. Without code, we can't really healp.

Comment: Is this version 3 bootstrap? are you using the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute? which is required regardless of whether you are planning to call the dropdown manually using `.dropdown()`

Comment: @Darkhogg: added; Pricey: yes, v3. See updated question re: attributes.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should add `dropdown` class to `li` element

and remove `<div class="dropdown">`

Hope to help:)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it did not work unfortunately